# Ranking Data Using CountIF

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am using this formula to rank data:

```
=(COUNTIF($N$4:$N$105,">="&$N4))
```

But it breaks if two of the values being ranked are the same.

It does not happen often but could happen that they have the exact same value. Any thoughts as to how to make this more dynamic to handle instances where the data could have the same value?

Comment: Have you tried combining RANK and COUNTIF [like so](http://www.mrexcel.com/td0067.html): RANK(A2,$A$2:$A$10)+COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use `RANK.EQ`

```
=RANK.EQ($N4,$N$4:$N$105)
```